# AWS - Lambda function - python script

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, openai-api

I'm trying to make the transcription from a video using the OpenAI's api, but I'm still having error related to the format of the file (video) present in the S3 bucket, how could I solve it?

Just to let you know, when I substitute the variable of the OPENAI_API_KEY directly with the value of the API_KEY I've got another type of error.

So, what could be the problem?

```
import os
import openai
import boto3
import time
import tempfile

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  
    # Set your OpenAI API key
    openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
    
    job_uri = "s3://s3uploadervideosgregory154442-dev/protected/eu-central-1:8a17a2d0-2aa9-4988-9ca7-195479e39756/prova_eliana.mp4"
    
    # Download the audio file from S3
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket_name = 's3uploadervideosgregory154442-dev'
    object_key = 'protected/eu-central-1:8a17a2d0-2aa9-4988-9ca7-195479e39756/prova_eliana.mp4'
    
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
    audio_data = response['Body'].read()
    
    # Create a temporary file to store the audio data
    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    temp_file.write(audio_data)
    temp_file.close()
    
    # Start audio transcription
    with open(temp_file.name, 'rb') as audio_file:
        response = openai.Audio.transcribe(file=audio_file, model="whisper-1", engine="davinci")
        transcription_id = response['id']
    
    # Now wait for the transcription to be completed
    while True:
        status = openai.Transcription.retrieve(transcription_id)
        transcription_status = status['status']
        
        if transcription_status in ['succeeded', 'failed']:
            break
        
        print("Not ready yet...")
        time.sleep(5)
    
    # Fetch the transcript once the transcription is complete
    if transcription_status == 'succeeded':
        transcript_text = status['response']['text']
        
        # Save the transcript text to the named S3 bucket
        s3.put_object(Bucket='transcribe-output-bucket-gregory', Key=object_key + '-transcript.txt', Body=transcript_text)
        
        # Clean up the temporary file
        os.remove(temp_file.name)
        
        return {
            "transcription_status": transcription_status,
            "transcript_saved": True
        }
    else:
        # Clean up the temporary file
        os.remove(temp_file.name)
        
        return {
            "transcription_status": transcription_status,
            "transcript_saved": False
        }
```

The error that I get:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unrecognized file format. Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']",
  "errorType": "InvalidRequestError",
  "requestId": "44ceeeaa-e76e-4a2e-a77d-05f6923e2a56",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 29, in lambda_handler\n    response = openai.Audio.transcribe(file=audio_file, model=\"whisper-1\", engine=\"davinci\")\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/openai/api_resources/audio.py\", line 65, in transcribe\n    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(\"post\", url, files=files, params=data)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/openai/api_requestor.py\", line 226, in request\n    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/openai/api_requestor.py\", line 620, in _interpret_response\n    self._interpret_response_line(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/openai/api_requestor.py\", line 683, in _interpret_response_line\n    raise self.handle_error_response(\n"
  ]
}
```